# nginx: ability to log if client supports TLS SNI?

Tags: nginx, ssl

I would like to get some statistics how many of our users are using a software which supports TLS SNI. Can nginx log these details? Based on the [nginx documentation about variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) I think the information is not available.

Alternatively I thought about adding yet another reverse proxy in front but I'm not sure which proxy logs that information. I found [snidump](https://github.com/kontaxis/snidump) but that project seems unmaintained and only supports TLS 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

> Based on the nginx documentation about variables I think the information is not available.

Citing from exactly the [same documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) you reference:

```
$ssl_server_name
returns the server name requested through SNI (1.7.0);
```

Thus, if no `ssl_server_name` is set than the client does not send the `server_name` extension, which means that the client does not use SNI.

Comment: Thank you - seems like I need to go back to school to improve my reading skills.